# .splice( $.inArray()) should only remove matching item

Tags: jquery, splice

I have five links. Each link has an id. I save each of these id's into an array.

When clicking on a link im trying to remove the matching clicked link id from within the array.

Im trying to do this with the following:

```
shuffledBlockIds.splice( $.inArray(removeItem, shuffledBlockIds), 1 );
```

The item removes fine with the first click, however if I click again it will simply remove yet another item (although the clicked id no longer exists).

**How do I only remove an item, if the clicked id exists in the array?**

Had a look at `indexOf()` but that should supposedly not work in IE8.

IE9+ solution would also be welcomed - just wondering if there's some smart Jquery approach also taking care of IE8.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dyoew9ga/

Comment: Seriously, still thinking about IE8? **Move on**.

Comment: I have, but id like to know if there actually is a solution with Jquery that perhaps easily takes IE8 into account - edited my description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `removeItem` is not present in `shuffledBlockIds`, [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) will return `-1`.

The [documentation for `splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) says (emphasis mine):

> **start**
>
> Index at which to start changing the array. If greater than the length of the array, actual starting index will be set to the length
>   of the array. **If negative, will begin that many elements from the end.**

Therefore, `splice()` will end up removing the last element from the array.

To work around this, use an explicit test:

```
var index = $.inArray(removeItem, shuffledBlockIds);
if (index >= 0) {
    shuffledBlockIds.splice(index, 1);
}
```